# PHP how to set content later or if is loaded?

Tags: php, jquery, delay, file-get-contents

Hello I have a website which loads data from an api to show the newest stats. I am storing it for 10 minutes to prevent loading api calls every time. Since there are many api calls it takes at first time like 5-10 seconds to finish loading the website which looks like the website would be down.

Currently I am using pure php for functionalities. There are functions like GetTotalEarnings() - just a file_get_contents($url) to receive a json content and decode it and put it to a table which I can use for 10 minutes. After 10 minutes it will call all apis again to refresh the values (if the page get reloaded of course).

To solve this my idea was to load the content first and show the content and then load the data to set values later. But I don't know where to start. I know jquery can do this with a call back but its javascript. I don't know what tot do there

Two examples how looks currently

```
<h1 class=""><center>Earnings Total: <?php echo GetTotalEarnings() . " (Latest update: " . GetLatestUpdateTime() . ")"; ?></center></h1>


<h1 class="">This Month</h1>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="box c1 center-block">
        <h4 class="blue">Today</h4>
        <span class="icon blue"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i></span>
        <span class="price-large blue"><?php echo round(GetTodayEarnings(), 2); ?></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to get data every 10 minutes then it sounds like a CRON job would be better suited to your needs. This would also speed up the front end as the user wouldn't have to wait for the data to be downloaded, as it would already have been done in the background.

Comment: This is not the problem. I made a file where I store the data for 10 minutes. After the time is done and the page gets reloaded so the file gets refreshed. I don't want to use cron job. Its ok for me if all data gets updated on the fly.

Comment: So you know you want to use javascript and maybe JQuery, but you do not know anything about those languages! So you will have to get a book and/or do some online tutorials. SO **is not** a tutorial site, and we dont **write code for you for free**

Comment: Maybe I described it wrong. I can use javascript or even jQuery without problems. Like you see I said "don't know where to start". I want just get Ideas about updating contents on pre loaded pages like I tried to describe above (as an idea). It can be jquery (ajax), or php with callbacks using just pure javascript. Just wanted few ideas.. not a code which I copy paste, @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of requesting the API data on a user request, I would instead have a background script/program running every 10 minutes which caches the results in [memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) or [MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mysqlinfo.php). Then when a user requests the data, return the cached results. If the API takes 10+ seconds to process, then without looking at the code to potentially optimise it we have to assume 10+ seconds is just how long it takes to process. Caching is the only way to speed up the user request without optimising the API.

You could use JavaScript to async load the script then modify the document once the page has loaded. Below is an example using Jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "myApiCalls.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: queryString,
            success: function(data) {
                // ...
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. The reason is why I try to avoid something like cronjobs is what if I decide to have the data in realtime. I mean to see the changes on every reload. Also the api requests have not always 10 seconds to process. Some of them are instant and some takes little bit time. Thats why I thought to load data "later" to the content or update content later. Well ok. I need to use jquery / ajax. If jquery can call functions of php this would be perfect. I will give a try

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Leon Storey, while reading his answer with "data: queryString," and answering him I had a nice idea which I want to show here ofc for people who has the problem too.

For people like @RiggsFolly who things I wanted just use a copy paste here get codes written for me and judging me first without understanding the problem (with even "-1" I think) I wanted to say again: My problem was that I have a many defined php functions which requests data from an external api (currently I store the data for 10 minutes, in this time it will not use the api). Since I said I want to make load content first then update values like numbers with the requests I didn't know where to start to work with it and use it together with jquery or maybe with other ideas. Just wanted to know what is there possible.

Now what I did to solve this.
Php has great two functions.

```
function_exists("func");

call_user_func("func");
```

with ajax together I made this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "apicalls.php",
        data: {callfunction: 'GetTotalEarnings'},
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

This will give an alert if api request is done. Now lets see the apicalls.php

```
include "apirequest.php";

if(isset($_POST['callfunction'])) {
    $func = $_POST['callfunction'];

    if(function_exists($func)) {
        echo call_user_func($func);
    } else {
        die("This function does not exists");
    }
}
```

This means I do not need to rewrite my "apirequest" php file. I just use a little helper like a pipeline to let it work with ajax requests. **The problem is now completely solved**

Comment: There is a potential security issue in that you're not checking the external data in `$_POST`, if someone knows the functions used in your script they could call whichever they want. Such as `apicalls.php?callfunction=MySuperSecretFunction`. You may want an `array` of publically accessible functions to check against.

Comment: Yea I already thought about it. I just took all restricted function out there. There are only "Gets" for api which is fine. But in the future I will change to array or something like that.